# Cooldown timer in a button

Tags: android, button, timer, progress-bar

I have a button in my application that I would like to only be clickable once every 60 seconds. Once it is clicked, it would be disabled and I would like some sort of a cooldown timer, like a progress bar inside the button that decreases as time remaining to next click decreases.

I'm using a `CountdownTimer` at the moment, but I would like to know how to do is to implement the progress bar inside the button as described above.

Comment: Why this was downvoted? No clue, seems to be a legit question so I'm up voting it

Answer (score 0):

You should use a TimerTask. [Here's example](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html) that I think is a perfect match for your question

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. I specifically wanted to know how to implement the progress bar in the button.

Comment: You may want to look at LayerDrawable http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html or you can go as low as Canvas or ShapeDrawable. Once your drawable is created you can set it as button drawable and have it registered to listen for any updates from the CountdownTimer